# In C#, how can I define a 'typedef struct' with pointer members for use in a call to a DLL

Tags: c#, pointers, dll, struct

I have a simple C# WPF windows application that needs to call a 'c' DLL.   I understand how to call dll functions with built-in datatypes and that works fine:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]  //CharSet = CharSet.Unicode
    public static extern int MessageBox(int hWnd, string msg, string title, uint flags);
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Boolean MessageBeep(UInt32 beepType);
}
 ...
 NativeMethods.MessageBeep ( 1 );
```

But now I want to use a dll whose header file is loaded with typedef structs that contain pointer elements that point to other typedef structs.   I'm new to the world of c#, but from what I've read pointers are a little different than in c/c++.

(i.e. from the MSDN:
A pointer cannot point to a reference or to a struct that contains references, because 
an object reference can be garbage collected even if a pointer is pointing to it. The garbage
collector not keep track of whether an object is being pointed to by any pointer types.)

So how does one pass pointer to structs (and receive) when calling a dll in c#?

Comment: Can you show this typedefs? Please show header file dll written in C, or at least part of it.

Comment: It's better to use C++/CLI. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef4c3t39.aspx) for general guidelines. As a rule of thumb: once you have heavy interop scenarios, and you are not a stranger to C++, write the wrapper layer in C++/CLI, exposing managed code - friendly API to your C# code.